# How to capitalise the first letter of each word after reversing a string

Tags: javascript

I want to make everything lowercase for when the string is reversed but then capitalise the first letter of each word after. I have reversed the string but after many attempts, the only outcome I can get is to then capitalise the entire reversed string.

```
function titleCase(str) {
var reversed = str.toLowerCase().split('').reverse();
var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < reversed.length; i++) {
    var firstLetter = reversed[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    var restOfWord = reversed[i].slice(1);
        newArr[i] = firstLetter + restOfWord;     
 }
 return newArr.join(''); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `toLowerCase()` if you need to convert it back to lowercase & css property 
`text-transform: capitalize` will capitalize first letter of every word

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var reversed = str.toLowerCase().split('').reverse();
  var newArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < reversed.length; i++) {
    var firstLetter = reversed[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    var restOfWord = reversed[i].slice(1);
    newArr[i] = (firstLetter + restOfWord).toLowerCase();
  }
  return newArr.join('');
}


document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = titleCase('Hello how are you')
```

```css
.test {
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here now it will work

```
 function titleCase(str) {
    var reversed = str.toLowerCase().split(' ').reverse();
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < reversed.length; i++) {
            reversed[i]=reversed[i].split("").reverse().join("");


    var firstLetter = reversed[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        var restOfWord = reversed[i].slice(1);
            newArr[i] = firstLetter + restOfWord;     
     }
     return newArr.join(' '); 
    }
```

Comment: This is giving me the capital letter at the start of each word but the word is now no longer reversed like I need it to be. I can't figure out how to have both at the same time.

Comment: do you want each word to be reversed?

Comment: Yeah so for instance 'hello HELLO' would become 'Olleh Olleh'. Sorry I should have put something like this in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  return str.split("").reverse().join("").toLowerCase();
}
document.getElementById('test').append(reverseString("Hello"));
```

```css
#test {
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

```html
<span id='test'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reversing the string, you need to join it back and `split` on spaces, so that inside your for loop you are only capitalising the first letter of each word.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
var reversed = str.toLowerCase().split('').reverse();
reversed = reversed.join('').split(' ');
var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < reversed.length; i++) {
    var firstLetter = reversed[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    var restOfWord = reversed[i].slice(1);
        newArr[i] = firstLetter + restOfWord;     
 }
 return newArr.join(' '); 
} 

console.log(titleCase('hello HELLO'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Input.
const before = 'hello WORLD'
console.log(`Before: ${before}`)

// Conversion.
const lowercase = before.toLowerCase()
const reversed = [...lowercase].reverse()
const capitalised = reversed.map((character, index) => {
  const isFirstCharacter = (index === 0)
  const isAfterWhiteSpace = isFirstCharacter ? false : (reversed[index-1] === ' ')
  if (isFirstCharacter || isAfterWhiteSpace) return character.toUpperCase()
  return character
})

// Output + Proof.
const after = capitalised.join('')
console.log(`After: ${after}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use replace and some fancy regex to do what you want.

```js
var sentence = "hello i am a world 12321321 ;[/>?]" 
console.log(sentence);
function titleCase(str) {
 return str.toLowerCase().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/\b\w/mg,
   (match)=>{return match.toUpperCase();}
 );
} 
console.log(titleCase(sentence));
```